# Slicing Array in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working with Java Api of elastic search.

Lets say I fetch below mentioned json data from elastic search.

```
  {
     "id":"123",
      "genres":[{"key":"EN","value":"action"},{"key":"FR","value":"action"}]
    },
    {
      "id":"234",
      "genres":[{"key":"EN","value":"action"},{"key":"FR","value":"drama"}]
    }
```

I want to slice/filter data on the basis of the value of key property.
For example on passing key as EN I want below mentioned data.
I have tried nested query but it did not work.

Expected output:

```
 {
     "id":"123",
      "genres":[{"key":"EN","value":"action"}]
    },
    {
      "id":"234",
      "genres":[{"key":"EN","value":"action"}]
    }
```

Can this be achieved in elastic search?

Comment: Yes, if your `genres` field is of `nested` type, it's possible to do it with a nested `inner_hits`. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773542/fetch-only-filtered-nested-objects-from-index-in-elasticsearch/32774267#32774267

Comment: Let me try this concept.

Comment: Unfortunately our code base is 1.4 and this concept is not present in that.

Comment: You know what to do: upgrade :-) 1.4 is not supported anymore