# Filter by id in array and return only item with id, Elasticsearch 1.7

Tags: elasticsearch

How to filter `offers` array by `id` field and return in results object with searched id?

Current search correctly find data by id in offers array but it also returns all objects it:

```
GET activities/activity/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "bool": {
               "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "offers.id": "12"
                    }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Current results, I would like to filter offers and get only that with `"id": 12`:

```
"hits": [
   {
      "_index": "activities",
      "_type": "activity",
      "_id": "AVtr4-UV81wMr8KFD246",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
         "offers": [
            {
               "title": "merge",
               "id": 11
            },
            {
               "title": "order test",
               "id": 12
            }
         ],
         "event": "candidate_remove",
         "created_at": "2017-04-14T09:55:49.115174Z"
      }
   }
]
```

mapping for offers in activity type:

```
"offers": {
   "type": "nested",
   "include_in_parent": true,
   "properties": {
      "id": {
         "type": "long"
      },
      "title": {
         "type": "string",
         "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
   }
},
```

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773542/fetch-only-filtered-nested-objects-from-index-in-elasticsearch/32774267#32774267

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32773542/5936696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `inner_hits` functionality and a `nested` query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "offers",
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "offers.id": "12"
                  }
                },
                "inner_hits":{}
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this will add another section in the response called `inner_hits` where it's showing the matching nested documents.

If you don't need the original `offers` value, you could add something like this to the original query:

```
{
  "_source": {"exclude": "offers"}, 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
```