# Make Elasticsearch return only searched result

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my source structure
[image]
when I search IP 

`?q=records.ip:10.8.189.24`

I want to get these results:
[image]

My mapping properties:
[image]

Can Elasticsearch make it?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773542/fetch-only-filtered-nested-objects-from-index-in-elasticsearch/32774267#32774267

Comment: @Val thanks, I solved it