# Is it possible to create an ElasticSeach search that only returns matching nested objects not all nested objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to construct an ElasticSearch search/query that only returns with the results those nested objects that match the nested object search criteria, not all of the nested objects?

For example...

```
{
   "product": "shoe 1",
   "available" [
       {
          "size" : "small",
          "color" : "red",
       },
       {
          "size" : "large",
          "color" : "blue",
       }
   ],
}
{
   "product": "shoe 2",
   "available" [
       {
          "size" : "medium",
          "color" : "red",
       }
       {
          "size" : "xtra large",
          "color" : "green",
       }
   ],
}
```

.. where a search for shoe color red would return....

```
{
   "product": "shoe 1",
   "available" [
       {
          "size" : "small",
          "color" : "red",
       },
   ],
}
{
   "product": "shoe 2",
   "available" [
       {
          "size" : "medium",
          "color" : "red",
       }
   ],
}
```

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773542/fetch-only-filtered-nested-objects-from-index-in-elasticsearch/32774267#32774267

Comment: The suggestion in that link does not work.  I am searching just on the 'color' field, and I get back all array elements for each doc

Comment: Post your query so we can see what you tried.

Comment: @user2868835 you can take the query as it is and modify it to search on the color field and it will work. The key here is to use the `inner_hits` feature. Show your query so we can see how you've done it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:

```
GET /my_index/products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "available",
            "score_mode": "max", 
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "available.color": "red"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```