# Elasticsearch -- How to find specific element on a json formatted field in your index

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named `web` with a field called `csr` that has a datatype of `string` -- the reason why we made it so, is because we have migrated from Mysql and is now trying to use Elasticsearch.

The `csr` field signifies the linked/joined data with another table during the Mysql phase (It shows that the `web` records **HAS MANY** linked `csr` records)

Here's an example screenshot of the index using Kibana:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to do a `range` query filter to display all the documents that belongs to a certain range of `csr.csr_story_value`. For example, I want to display documents that has a `csr.csr_story_value` values ranging from `4 to 5`. However, since there are multiple json elements in the `csr` field, I presume that the query points out to the highest value in the `csr` field. Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

**MAIN QUESTION**

Is there a way in Elastcisearch to insert a `match` query in this `range` query so I can specifically match my `kgp_id` and `cli_id` to just specifically pick a certain json element in this field?

Comment: Your `csr` field needs to have the `nested` data type. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32773542/fetch-only-filtered-nested-objects-from-index-in-elasticsearch/32774267#32774267

Comment: hello sir @Val, I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, an error message occurs to me, `[nested] nested object under path [csr] is not of nested type`. Is there any workaround for this without using nested?

Comment: You need to make sure that the index is created with `csr` being nested

Comment: Hello sir @Val is this the right way to do sorting for such `nested` fields? https://pastebin.com/raw/PKaFtAPz