# Elasticsearch -- sort documents according to a value from a nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch: v7.2 
Application: Laravel v5.7

This is a continuation of my Elasticsearch series with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944343/elasticsearch-how-to-find-specific-element-on-a-json-formatted-field-in-your).

As a result of migrating from MySql to Elasticsearch, our former database tables are required to produce `JOINED` results from another tables. When we turned our database table to Elasticsearcch Indexes, we transformed the supposed to be `JOINED` results to become a `NESTED` object in our indexes

We are now able to fetch specific documents with the right parameters from a `nested` object such as: finding documents in our `web` index with a `csr` field that has a `csr.csr_story_value` of `3`

Now, our dilemma is, we are supposed to sort these documents, let's say, I was able to fetch the documents with a range of `csr.csr_story_value` from `3` to `4` but needs to `SORT` them accordingly in a `desc` and `asc` manner.

This is my code:

```
$temp = 
[
    "csr.csr_story_value" => [
        'order' => $order,
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'csr',
            'filter' => [
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [
                        [ 
                          "match" => [ 
                            "csr.cli_id" => $parseParams['client_media_xref---cli_id']
                          ] 
                        ],
                        [
                          "match" => [
                            "csr.kgp_id" => $parseParams['client_media_xref---kgp_id']
                          ]
                        ],
                        [ 
                          "range" => [
                            "csr.csr_story_value" => [
                              "gte" => (int)$parseParams['cmx_story_rank---csr_story_rank'],
                              "lt" => (int)($parseParams['cmx_story_rank---csr_story_rank'])
                            ]
                          ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];

$params['body']['sort'] = $temp;
```

The problem is, the documents were not being sorted out. Am I missing something or any queries for the Elasticsearch nested object sorting?

Sample output (still not being sorted):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a series of trial and error, I should have just removed the `range` query and add a `mode` of `avg`. My working query now:

```
$temp = 
[
    "csr.csr_story_value" => [
        'order' => $order,
        'nested' => [
            'path' => 'csr',
            'filter' => [
                "bool" => [
                    "must" => [
                        [ 
                          "match" => [ 
                            "csr.cli_id" => $parseParams['client_media_xref---cli_id']
                          ] 
                        ],
                        [
                          "match" => [
                            "csr.kgp_id" => (string)$parseParams['client_media_xref---kgp_id']
                          ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        "mode" => "avg"
    ]
];
```