# Elasticsearch change response format

Tags: jquery, json, elasticsearch

I am saving multiple file data to **Elasticsearch** using `/cairn/_doc/id` where id is unique id of file. The sample data is like below.

```
var file = 1;
var meraData = '{"data":[{"page":"1","lineid":"00f6","text":"OIL AND NATURAL ","fileId":"175"},{"page":"1","lineid":"4411","text":"Source Rock Geochemistry","fileId":"175"},{"page":"1","lineid":"c267","text":"CHENNAI -600034","fileId":"175"}]}';
function sendElastic(meraData, file){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'https://search-cairn-o3fpbj34hxgttac6b3dnuc37ie.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/cairn/_doc/'+file,
        data:JSON.stringify(meraData),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data.responseJSON);
        }
    });
}
```

After making a **GET** request to `cairn/_search?q=OIL`
reponse is like below.

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 0.57148063,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "cairn",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.57148063,
        "_source": {
          "data": [
            {
              "page": "1",
              "lineid": "00f6",
              "text": "OIL AND NATURAL ",
              "fileId": "175"
            },
            {
              "page": "1",
              "lineid": "4411",
              "text": "Source Rock Geochemistry",
              "fileId": "175"
            },
            {
              "page": "1",
              "lineid": "c267",
              "text": "CHENNAI -600034",
              "fileId": "175"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I change the response format to show only exact matched array value in _source.data array?
For example, for query "OIL"

```
{
  "page": "1",
  "lineid": "00f6",
  "text": "OIL AND NATURAL ",
  "fileId": "175"
}
```

should return in _source.data

Or is it possible to save it like `/cairn/_doc/id/lineid` ?

Comment: You need to store source.data as nested type and use nested query to get exact match. Refer link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html for further details

Comment: @jaspreetchahal I used nested query too. Even if I get the exact match, the response includes all source.data array instead of matched array key.

Comment: this answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774267/4604579 (hint: use nested `inner_hits`)